# Ajax form submission

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

I am trying to post the a form using ajax but the form never submits. Debugging using firebug doesn't show any errors. any help is appreciated. i am new to PHP and coding.

Taskload.php - Pushes data to the main page:

```
    <?php
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

            $varacctname = $_REQUEST['acct'];
            $varViewtasks = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE taskresource = '$varacctname' AND taskstatus='Active'");
                while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($varViewtasks)) {
                    $accttask = $rows['tasktitle'];
                    $acctTaskStatus = $rows['taskstatus'];
                    $taskOwner = $rows['taskOwnerFullName'];
                    $taskid = $rows['taskid'];
                    echo "<div class=\"timeline-messages\">
                                  <div class=\"msg-time-chat\">
                                      <a href=\"#\" class=\"message-img\"><img class=\"avatar\" src=\"img/chat-avatar.jpg\" alt=\"\"></a>
                                      <div class=\"message-body msg-in\">
                                          <span class=\"arrow\"></span>
                                          <div class=\"text\">
                                              <p class=\"attribution\"><a href=\"#\">$taskOwner</a></p>
                                              <p> $accttask</p>
                                          </div>
                                          <form id=\"completetaskform\"  method=\"post\" >
                                            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"taskid\" value=\"$taskid\" />
                                            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"acct\" value=\"$varacctname\" />
                                            <input type=\"submit\" id=\"completetaskbtn\" class=\"btn btn-success\" />  
                                          </form>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                            </div>";
                }
?>
```

Tasks.js - where the script lives

```
  $("#completetaskform").submit(function(){

            $.ajax ({
              type:"POST",
              url:"functions//completeTask.php",
              data: $('form#completetaskform').serialize(),
              success: function(msg){
                notifyTaskCompleted();
                location.reload();

              },
            });
            return false;
          });
```

completeTask.php Where the php code runs to mark task as completed.

```
  <?php
    include 'dbconnect.php';

    $acct = $_POST['acct'];
    $taskid = $_POST['taskid'];
    $complete = 'completed';
    mysql_query("UPDATE tasks SET taskstatus='$complete' WHERE taskresource='$acct' AND taskid='$taskid' ");
       ?>
```

--On the main page , i have tasks.js included in  - Hope this may describe the issue better.

Comment: I don't think a double slash is legal in a URL.

Comment: @ShreyosAdikari The backslashes in the HTML are probably because the form is PHP-generated (hence the dollar sign prefixed variables).

Comment: @ShreyosAdikari — Probably because someone has copy/pasted their HTML out of a PHP string instead of drop out of PHP mode for the HTML.

Comment: Slashes are inserted in the form because its enclosed in PHP tags.

Comment: Wouldn't it be interpreted as a protocol delimiter? @Quentin

Comment: @11684 — Only at the start or after the first `:`

Comment: Why use Ajax if you're going to `location.reload();` as soon as it is done?

Comment: If the form doesn't submit, what does happen? Are any HTTP requests made? Is the function called?

Comment: @user3470172 What do you mean with 'the form never submits'? Is the callback never called, or is your server not receiving anything? Or maybe the page doesn't reload?

Comment: @Quentin the page reloads and nothing changes. and i cannot track any issues in debugger since the page reloads.

Comment: @user3470172 - You can configure the debugger to persist its content between pages.

Comment: <input type=\"submit\" id=\"#completetaskbtn\" class=\"btn btn-success\"> Complete </a> -> ? use w3c validator you will see there's a few input you absolutly have to close (<input ytpe="submit" value="send" />)

Comment: @Quentin  Thanks,. tried and no changes. i dont see the php code being called. The JS is included in the page.

Comment: @Bene — Nonsense. There is no indication that the OP is using XHTML. If there were, and it was causing a problem, then that problem would be the very obvious yellow screen of death.

Comment: Your server-side script doesn't output anything meaningful to the ajax calling script to tell you whether you had success or failure. You are also doing nothing at all try check for and handle errors in the PHP script as it relates to DB access.

Comment: @user3470172 — So your debugger is set to persist the console across pages and no errors at all are showing up? What if you turn on Break On Any Exception on the scripts pane? What if you add a deliberate error to the JS?

Comment: Could it be because the form is generated using PHP the JS never runs?? i am just thinking loud.

Comment: @Quentin did breaks and no errors on the page.

Comment: @user3470172 — No. PHP outputs text to the browser. It won't stop JS from running. The browser can't tell the difference.

Comment: The form is part of an echo from PHP.

Comment: What happens if you put `alert( $("#completetaskform").length );` just before the JS you have in the question?

Comment: When i added     <script src="CJS/TaskLoad.js"></script> to the bottom of the PHPO Page which pushes the form to the page. it works but it crashes the page with constant requests. Taskload is the js where the completeTask function is.

Comment: As already mentioned, some of your inputs are missing the starting `<` which will fail, which very well be the principal cause. `input type=\"text\" name=\"taskid\" value=\"$taskid\" />` to `<input type=\"text\" name=\"taskid\" value=\"$taskid\" />` and `input type=\"text\" name=\"acct\" value=\"$varacctname\" />` to `<input type=\"text\" name=\"acct\" value=\"$varacctname\" />`

Comment: @Fred-ii- There are there. not sure why they didnt paste when i created the thread.

Comment: Ah ok. I edited your question, if you say they are in your actual code. @user3470172

Comment: Btw, why the `</a>` in `<input type=\"submit\" id=\"#completetaskbtn\" class=\"btn btn-success\"> Complete </a>`? @user3470172 That is invalid. You may have meant `<input type=\"submit\" id=\"#completetaskbtn\" class=\"btn btn-success\" value="Complete">` ? Or is that another copy/paste error?

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks.. i also removed the </a>

Comment: Do update your question with the actual code then. No sense in commenting back and forth with what is and what should be; it's confusing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i will edit the post for better explanation. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see an edit yet. @user3470172

Comment: @Fred-ii- please see the reformatted code. hope this helps. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after many trials, i found that changing the the form data section to $(this).serialize worked instead of $('form#completetaskform').serialize(). Not sure why but this worked. Thank you.

```
$("form#completetaskform").submit(function(){
        $.ajax ({
          type:"POST",
          url:"Functions/completeTask.php",
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          success: function(msg){
            notifyTaskCompleted();
            location.reload();

          },
        });
        return false;
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

try [SerializeArray](https://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/&ei=vYA0U8mDAaO40QXjm4C4Dw&usg=AFQjCNHrQoYgyrnW7f5IHy4hw6wdF_pz5g&sig2=9u1lkWEZB7Qvty1J9dIudw&bvm=bv.63808443,d.d2k)

```
 $("#completetaskform").submit(function(){

        $.ajax ({
          type:"POST",
          url:"functions//completeTask.php",
          data: $('form#completetaskform').serialize(),
          success: function(msg){
            notifyTaskCompleted();
            location.reload();

          },
        });
        return false;
      });
```

or even `$.post`

```
$.post('functions/completeTrask.php',$('form#completetaskform').serialize(),function(){
            notifyTaskCompleted();
            location.reload();
});
```

Comment: Why would either of those help? These suggestions sound like attempts at rewriting the syntax in the hope that the problem will go away instead of being based on any understanding of what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

1.Change

```
$("#completetaskform").submit(function(){
```

to

```
$("#completetaskform").on('click',function(){
```

Because jquery event is ".on()", not ".submit()"

2.Change

```
<input type=\"submit\" id=\"#completetaskbtn\" class=\"btn btn-success\"> Complete </a>
```

to

```
<button id="completetaskbtn"> Complete </button>
```

Bacause you don't need real submit button.

3.I'm not sure that your url is correct but this will submit your form to php.

Comment: Not sure why we got downvoted (but I gave you an up.) I agree the op's problem is he is not catching the submit event properly.

Answer (score -1):

I would use a generic button and click handler instead of a submit button and the submit event. Try this:

```
<button type=\"button\" id=\"#completetaskbtn\" class=\"btn btn-success\"> Complete </button>
```

Then attach a click event to it

```
$("#completetaskbtn").on('click', function () {
    // the rest of the code you have
});
```